# how do I login as primary using tightvnc

Tags: vnc

I did the mistake with setting similar password for "view only" and "primary" mode using tightvnc server. Now I only can control my client pc and everytime I want to log in to server, I always logged in to "view only". Am I right, since I have similar password so I always redirected to "view only" mode or any idea how I can log in to primary without changing password from server?

Really thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to the server, you must specify whether you are connecting in view-only mode or full-access mode. The password that's required depends on what mode you ask for; the level of access is not determined by what password you use.

**Edit**

If you're using TightVNC Viewer, click "Options" and in the section marked "Restrictions" uncheck

> View only (inputs ignored)

Other viewers should be relatively similar.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm using tightsvn viewer in windows now and cannot find option how to do that. Can you give me any clue?

Comment: @Mr.K I updated my answer to include the name of the checkbox in TightVNC viewer

Comment: I've let it unchecked from the beginning since it was default configuration and I remain unabled to control my pc totally and it showed small rectangle node, seems I cannot control remote pointer/mouse.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what your issue is. you should update your answer to include screenshots. For future reference this is better suited to superuser; I expect it will be migrated there soon

Comment: Unfortunately my image cannot be attached along this post, since my reputation is only one. Thanks for your aid however.

Comment: @Mr.K ah, keep forgetting that. here, have one upvote.